# scrollbar plugin with easing and touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been searching for a nice jquery or css plugin for scrollbars that have touch enabled and easing and I can't find one. Does anyone know of a good scrollbar plugin that has that criteria(even if has a price tag on it) and can be customized to you're liking

Answer (score 0):

i use this one. Easy to use and customizable https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/